# Cancel an already executing task in Python RQ?

Tags: python, heroku, redis, python-rq

I am using http://python-rq.org/ to queue and execute tasks on Heroku worker dynos. These are long-running tasks and occasionally I need to cancel them in mid-execution. How do I do that from Python?

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from my_module import count_words_at_url

q = Queue(connection=Redis())
result = q.enqueue(
             count_words_at_url, 'http://nvie.com')
```

and later in a separate process I want to do:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
from my_module import count_words_at_url

q = Queue(connection=Redis())
result = q.revoke_all() # or something
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If so, I'd love if you'd post the solution.  Thx

Comment: I didn't, unfortunately. I had to work way around it.

Comment: Relevant (but closed) github issue here: https://github.com/nvie/rq/issues/339

Answer (score 13):

If you have the job instance at hand simply

```
job.cancel()
```

Or if you can determine the hash:

```
from rq import cancel_job
cancel_job('2eafc1e6-48c2-464b-a0ff-88fd199d039c')
```

http://python-rq.org/contrib/

But that just removes it from the queue; I don't know that it will kill it if already executing.

You could have it log the wall time then check itself periodically and raise an exception/self-destruct after a period of time.

For manual, ad-hoc style, death: If you have `redis-cli` installed you can do something drastic like flushall queues and jobs:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> flushall
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

[I'm still digging around the documentation](http://redis.io/commands/client-kill) to try and find how to make a precision kill.

Not sure if that helps anyone since the question is already 18 months old.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most common solution is to have the worker spawn another thread/process to do the actual work, and then periodically check the job metadata.  To kill the task, set a flag in the metadata and then have the worker kill the running thread/process.

Comment: Can you please elaborate for how the worker may access the job metadata? Are you sure the job metadata is a accessible for the worker dynamically, i.e. that changes in the job metadata are reflected in realtime to the worker?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://python-rq.org/docs/workers/#stopping-a-job):

> You can use `send_stop_job_command()` to tell a worker to immediately
> stop a currently executing job. A job that’s stopped will be sent to
> FailedJobRegistry.

```py
from redis import Redis
from rq.command import send_stop_job_command

redis = Redis()
send_stop_job_command(redis, job_id)
```